# Create a function based on timeout in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, function, timeout

I want to make a function that returns something within significant time. The function should return some predefined value if timeout. for example,

```
func loginFunc(timeOut: Int) {
        
    Login.getUSerAuthenticaiton(email: "abc@zyf.com", password: "123456789", completion: {_,_ in 
            print("Reponse")
    })
}
```

call Function like,

```
loginFunc(timeOut: 10)
```

Means, the function should run for 10 seconds after that it should return nil. Make sure it will be an API call or it can be a normal funtion.

Comment: What does it even mean that the function should run for 10 seconds? I assume you don't mean it should have it's own run loop? Is `Login.getUSerAuthenticaiton` an async call and you want to terminate if it hasn't received a reply within 10 seconds? Please clarify what you mean.

Comment: Yup exactly! The function should run only for 10 seconds. `Login.getUSerAuthenticaiton` an async call and I want to terminate it if I can not get a response in 10 seconds.

Comment: So basically Alexander has got it right in the answer below, it just needs some minor adjustments.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**First way:**

```
 let timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: 10, repeats: false) { timer in
       print("Time is Over")
    }
    Login.getUSerAuthenticaiton(email: "abc@zyf.com", password: "123456789", completion: {_,_ in
            print("Reponse")
        timer.invalidate()
    })
```

You can invalidate timer if a response will faster than 10 sec and timer callback will never fired

**Second way:**

```
func loginFunc(timeOut: Int) {
    
    var isResponseGet = false
    
    let timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: 10, repeats: false) { timer in
        if isResponseGet {
            print("<##>Already get a rtesponse")
        } else {
            print("10 secs left and i didn't get a response")
        }
    }
    Login.getUSerAuthenticaiton(email: "abc@zyf.com", password: "123456789", completion: {_,_ in
            print("Reponse")
        isResponseGet = true
    })
}
```

Comment: It is clearly mentioned that Function should run for 10 seconds. If I get a response in 10 seconds it is good. If I am not getting a response in 10 seconds function should return nil. And I want something so that I can provide a time limit as a parameter.

Comment: You can create a Bool flag here, and return it to true in api callback and in timer check this variable on true